# PHP var_dump() in xdebug ignores __debugInfo() magical method

Tags: php, xdebug

Xdebug seems to ignore PHP magic method `__debugInfo()` in user defined classes when using `var_dump()`.

This is especially unhandy when injecting dependencies (with dependencies, with dependencies...).

Is there a setting for Xdebug's `var_dump()` so it works with `__debugInfo()` as expected? Or a workaround in PHP maybe? I could not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xdebug's philosophy is to show data as it exists in objects, to aid debugging. Having all the properties shown, and not just the ones that `__debugInfo()` returns follows this convention.

There is a [workaround for step debugging](https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1777#c5735), but not for the overloaded `var_dump()`. You can turn off Xdebug's "Development Tools" however, by not including `develop` in the `xdebug.mode` php.ini setting.